# Do MRI scans take energy from the electro-magnet?

Tags: superconductivity, electromagnetic-induction, perpetual-motion

I read that a MRI machine generates a powerful magnetic field produced by an electric current. In order to get a high current (and a strong magnetic field) without too much heat as a side effect, superconducting material is used. And it is cooled by liquid helium.

Keeping the temperature of liquid helium, the tension can be turned off and the machine works as a permanent magnet because the current keeps running (the resistance is zero).

If the magnet has to be turned off for some reason, it is necessary to let the helium temperature increases. So, the superconductivity is destroyed.

My question is: shouldn't the changes of the magnetic field due to interaction with the nucleous of the patients cells slow down the current? I think of a induced tension opposite to the currect flow. But I can not see why it should oppose the electric flow.

It seems to me as a kind of perpetual motion machine otherwise.

Comment: Once the nuclei start precessing they don't need additional to keep going. It's similar to a gyroscope in a gravitational field.The flipping of the spins is done with a low energy RF pulse - typically around $40$ MHz - which has an independent energy source.

Answer (score 0):

A MRI does indeed interact with its environment.  There is a small effective resistance due to joints or "flux movement resistance."  The effect is small, but it does indeed exist.

I believe the interaction between turning off the magnet and letting the temperature of the helium rise that you describe is backwards.  You turn the magnet off because, should the temperature rise too much, a quench occurs, dumping all of the energy in the magnet rather suddenly.